# Problem with Exit the application

Tags: iphone

Iam developing an application in which there is a AlertView which has 2 button saying
"OK" "Cancel" by pressing OK button My application will exit and goto the home screen of iphone so i used exit(0) code, does apple allows to exit in this way or there is any other way to the exit from the application? Please suggest some solution?

Thank You...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the only legal way to exit application programmatically. Although Apple states in its HIG that the correct way to terminate application is to press home button.

This question is well discussed on SO. (see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707685/how-to-quit-an-iphone-app-nicely/1707720#1707720) and you can easily find others using site search)