# How to terminate an iPhone application through a TabBaritem in Interface Builder?

Tags: iphone, interface-builder

I have developed an iPhone app where there are four tab bar items and if i press the last TabBar the application should terminate. How to do it in Interface Builder?

Comment: I vaguely remember the Apple guidelines specifically tell you not to have a quit button. Besides the fact that it's not necessary, if you want to get it approved, don't have one.

Answer (score 2):

Terminating the app must involve code. It can’t be done simply in IB. And there’s no documented and clean way to quit the app besides `exit(0)`, see [one of the previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707685/how-to-quit-an-iphone-app-nicely) on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

In the action you can write "[[UIApplication sharedApplication] terminateWithSuccess];"
And in the head file you add 
"@interface UIApplication (extended)
-(void) terminateWithSuccess;
@end"

Comment: And then your app will be rejected from the app store for using undocumented API.

Answer (score 0):

No vagaries.

Never **ever** quit the app programmatically.