# extend functionality of UIAlertView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uialertview

I am using a **UIAlertView** with a message *Peer Disconnected*.Back ground works/remaining codes are working without dismiss it.there is a button called **Continue**. I need to work the remaining codes only after the continue button click.
and also I need to Quit my application in cancel button click.can any one tell me a good way to do it.

**My Code is:**

```
UIAlertView *alertView;  
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Peer Disconnected!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Comment: see my edited answer and go through that link

Comment: got it [[NSThread mainThread] exit]

Comment: may i know that what will happen if i didnt click my continue button.

Comment: if there is net work chat app,can i able to receive mwssages without clicking continue?

Comment: If you dont click any of the buttons, the alert will remain there. Upon clicking buttons, the delegate method with index of clicked button will get called as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call UIAlertView's delegate method explained below......

```
 - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
 {
      if (buttonIndex == 0) {
          //Your Code   //For First Button
      } else if (buttonIndex == 1) {
          //Your Code   //For Second Button
      }
 }
```

Please follow this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application) to quit the application

Comment: basically i am a C# developer.tell me the code to quit my application in objective c.

Comment: @Sharmain The expectation is that application should never quit on its own.

Comment: If there is no internet connection and your app requires always connected to internet. Example is urban spoon app.

Answer (score 1):

try this:-

```
UIAlertView *alertView;  
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Peer Disconnected!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alert didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{   
    if(buttonIndex==0)
    {
NSLog(@"cancel clicked");
    }
    else if(buttonIndex==1)
    {
NSLog(@"continue clicked");
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UIAlertView *alertView;  
alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Peer Disconnected!" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Continue", nil];
[alertView show];
[alertView release];
```

Implement this delegate method.

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
if(buttonIndex == alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
// Cancel operation...
}else if (buttonIndex == alertView.firstOtherButtonIndex) {
// Continue operation...
}
}
```

Comment: basically i am a C# developer.tell me the code to quit my application in objective c.

Comment: Refer posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355168/proper-way-to-exit-iphone-application and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707685/how-to-quit-an-iphone-app-nicely