# How can I change the language of the displayed UIKeyboard from within my iPhone app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uikeyboard

Within my iPhone application, I'd like to change the language of the displayed UIKeyboard.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 6):

From the [iPhone Application Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TextandWeb/TextandWeb.html):

> Depending on the needs of your program and the user’s preferred language, the system might display one of several different keyboards. Although **your application cannot
>   control the user’s preferred language**
>   (and thus the keyboard’s input
>   method), it can control attributes of
>   the keyboard that indicate its
>   intended use, such as the
>   configuration of any special keys and
>   its behaviors.
>
> [...]
>
> To facilitate the language preferences
>   of different users, iPhone OS also
>   supports different input methods and
>   keyboard layouts for different
>   languages, some of which are shown in
>   Figure 5-4. **The input method and
>   layout for the keyboard is determined
>   by the user’s language preferences.**

So it appears there's no way to bring up a keyboard of a different language than the user's preference.

Comment: Duolingo does that, so it's not impossible.

Answer (score 2):

really cant do it programatically, the user must have that keyboard enabled and then they can get to it, you can maybe tell the user they require a non english keyboard in an alert view or something like that.

Comment: Then they can choose to use it, u can't force it programatically

Comment: Duolingo does that, so it's not impossible.

Answer (score -1):

```
NSString *iso631Code = @"zh";

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:iso631Code] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

gives me a Chinese (pinyin) keyboard (you can even dynamically switch between say @"zh", @"fr", @"en" without having to restart).

see also [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

Comment: hmm apparently messing with the keyboard settings in the general tab disables this somehow which is unfortunate. However, if you select "iOs Simulator" -> "Reset Content And Settings" then run your app with this code you'll see the different keyboard. I'm not sure which keyboard setting messes this up (maybe the fact they've been changed at all).