# How to check if keyboard is installed on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, uikeyboard, uikeyboardtype, iphone

How can I programmatically check if a particular keyboard (in my case, Chinese handwriting) is installed on iOS (4.3)?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: You can't, at least App Store legally with Apple's public APIs.

A little longer answer: This might be possible with a hacked/jailbroken device, but I have never seen methods to accomplish this task.

Comment: Thanks esqew. This [link](http://www.neoos.ch/news/46-development/54-uikeyboardtypenumberpad-and-the-missing-return-key) has a solution on iPhone, but does not work on iPad. I'm looking for sth similar, if possible.

Comment: That link will certainly not tell you how to "check if a particular keyboard... is installed."

Comment: Right. It only tells you what keyboard is presently selected through "UIView/hasPrefix", I guess. That'd be a good start. If I had that working for iPad, I could tell the user to install the keyboard and come back when done.

Comment: Just got that working on iPad, but it does not give details on the type of keyboard that appears: `<UIPeripheralHostView: 0x58d5250; frame = (0 760; 768 264); autoresizesSubviews = NO; layer = <UIPeripheralHostLayer: 0x58d6130>>` is the same for all types of keyboard.

Comment: As esqew rightly said, and as this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784935/how-can-i-bring-up-the-iphone-uikeyboard-with-non-english-language) confirms it, it's not possible. Hope iOS5 will bring some changes here...