# How to change the language of UIkeyboard in iphone Programmatically?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is it possible to change the language of keyboard in iphone Programmatically? In my app, I want change the appearance of key board to Dutch language, how to do this?

Comment: Not possible, determined by user preferences. See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1784935/how-can-i-bring-up-the-iphone-uikeyboard-with-non-english-language

Answer (score 1):

its depend upon your phone settings. There is no need of code. if your phone language id dutch then keyboard also shows dutch language. but make sure that don't write kay board type  UIkeyboardtypealphatebic , becoz if you write this then default english keyboard appears. So remove it from your code...

Comment: Is it possible to change the return button title in the keyboard also i don't want to add custom button(with some other title) to keyboard.