# How to set the language of iPhone at the run time

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, ipad, localization

I have Login view on which I want to provide drop-down for language selection. So is it possible to change the language of application at the run-time.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up your own Translation-Framework. So read out the selected language and present the actual language for the user.
Apple, won't give you something in this direction. It's only possible to use `NSLocalizedString(@"Key", @"Description")`

Answer (score -1):

No !  What I do is using my own translation framework to support just that !