# Reset tab bar controller when change a language

Tags: iphone, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller

Where i should put this code in my app to reset tab bar controller i found this solution in below link in stackoverflow 
[Change language in app - how to restart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4749213/change-language-in-app-how-to-restart)

```
((AppDelegate)UIApplication.SharedApplication.Delegate).MainTabBarController.Reset();
public class MainTabBarController : UITabBarController
{
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    Reset();
    SelectedIndex = 2;
}

public void Reset()
{
    ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]
    {
        new ViewControllerTab1(),
        new ViewControllerTab2(),
        new ViewControllerTab3(),
        new ViewControllerTab4(),
        new ViewControllerTab5()
    };
}
}
```

Comment: Is this mono touch? If so, please tag appropriately.

Comment: Did you know what is the equivalent of this code in Objective c

Comment: Sort of, its not that simple though, with seeing the rest of your code.

Comment: Ok how i can implemented in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the Reset method from whatever component of your UI is changing the language.

Comment: Excuse me can you get me the equivalent of this code in objective c with example , i appreciate your effort