# How to use NSLocalization?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to add two button in Application and perform Some Operation. I want to Switch two language button in XIB. Suppose There are Button, 1 is English and 2 is French. I add some data in Application. If I select English Button then data is show in English language and French button it convert into Frech Language.

How I do used it? Please Give me a code for that.

Thanks in Advance.....

Rahul Rana

Answer (score 1):

You need to use something along the lines of whats discussed: [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

Answer (score 0):

I found this blog to be the best for learning Localization...

[Localization](http://www.raywenderlich.com/)

Hope that will help you a lot & solve your problem.