# When the device language changes, backgrounded apps quit themselves

Tags: ios

I've observed that if I change the device language, and after coming back to home screen, all background processes quit themselves. If I click on a running app icon again, it starts from scratch -- i.e., from `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`.

Am I wrong somewhere? What can I do to work around this?

Comment: I think that is normal behaviour, apps must be relaunched if the language changes

Comment: @phix23 : yes got it.. but user will definitely need to see current screen of running app when they come back to home screen.

if it is normal behavior .. then its fine. thankQ :)

Comment: rest assured - it IS normal behaviour :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a nothing odd and a default behavior.

You may want to look into this post if you want to make changes right from inside your application, though I am not sure on how good this is, as I have not personally implemented it.

[language change only after restart on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5912018/language-change-only-after-restart-on-iphone)

Let me know if you need more help.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: hey .. that answer is not relevant to my question.. sry