# Language changing option?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change language inside an application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155929/change-language-inside-an-application)

How can we implement language change option inside the  app rather then go to main settings n all . I work on application and i have to give language change option inside the app. Can any one suggest me the good tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous other questions similar to this. Pls dont ask duplicate questions. Anyway take a look at the answers in this previous SO question [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

Hope it helps