# Localization application in Chinese and English

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, localization

I am creating an application in which I want to do localization in two languages:

**1)English

2)Chinese**

I have done the whole app with a simple localization method and it works fine for me.

But now problem is, if the user chooses his/her language through option of language selection in application as a Chinese or English it will convert the whole application as per language without quit or restart the application.

Any suggestions ???

Comment: You should leave localization choice up to the Settings app.

Comment: not possible, i must implement the functionality of language chosen in application and in setting both.

Comment: Tell whoever set the requirements that he is wrong. On iOS, language should only be changed via the settings app.

Comment: @Julio and **force** him/her to read and understand the HIG.

Comment: hi hiren how to solve this issue please help me and give sort code

Comment: Tell whoever made the requirements that with these requirements, the app will be rejected from the app store. That's usually an argument that even the most pointy haired boss will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible and quite easy, have a look at [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920)