# how to switch language at runtime inside the app?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, internationalization

I have a requirement to switch UI language at run-time by opening and selecting a popup menu. I did some reading on cocoa's internationalization but found it not suitable for my project since it requires user to make changes in the system setting.

Post like "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language" suggests setting the `AppleLanguages` would also require an app-restart.

I wonder if I can (a) create multiple NIBs and call `initWithNib` according to the current language or (b) use one NIB but create a plist of strings and make a function to set title string for all the texts in all my `viewWillAppear`. Which solution sounds better or please let me if there is a third way.

Thanks
Leo

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is reloading all your views, and updating the text property of all text components (such as `UILabel`, `UITextField`, etc.). The language specific text to be set can be returned by a method of yours, something like-

```
-(NSString*) localizedStringForKey: (NSString*)key andLanguage: (NSString*)lang
{
    if([lang isEqualToString:@"en"])
    {
         if(key == @"hello")
              return @"Hello";

         //and so on...
    }

    else if([lang isEqualToString:@"fr"])
    {
         if(key == @"hello")
              return @"Bonjour";

         //and so on...
    }

}
```

P.S: Here I am returning hard-coded values, but you can read them from language-specific plists of yours.