# MKReverse Geocoder - Response Language

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkreversegeocoder

I am using MapKit and MKReverseGeocoder in order to convert lat/lon to location. 
I made some tests and realize that the geocoding response language is set according to iPhone's selected language. How do I set response language explicitly ? I want the response to be in 'en'  no matter what.
My code is:

```
MKReverseGeocoder *geocoder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:center];
[geocoder setDelegate:self];
[geocoder start];
```

Answer (score 3):

`MKReverseGeocoder` (also `CLGeocoder` in iOS5) does not allow you to set the language.

However you can build your own reverse geocoder using the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/intl/en-us/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding).
That requires to send an HTTP request and parse the response data.
You can set set language in the URL. Here is a list of supported languages: https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1

Example URL:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&sensor=true&language=en
```

Comment: Thats really cool, with this way you don't need to add if define branches inside of your code. Thanks @phix23 It was helped me lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can "trick" the app to think it's a specific "language"

see [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

short answer  put this in your main.m. In the "autorelease".

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]     
setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"en"]     
forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

for english geocoding

it might have other effects on your app if you use localization.