# Chosing language in application - objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, localization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

How to change language in my application? I have 2 localizations: english and russian. Language changes when i change my system language in iPhone. But i want to change language in my own application by user. How to do this?

Comment: Have a look at this. [How to change your language]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920