# Change language of the ios application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4, localization

I've put my app settings into iPhone Settings panel. I want to switch between languages independently of the iPhone system language. Is it possible? I'm using this advice:
   [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920)

But it translates only string inside app, but my nib files are same. How to reload my nibs?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The key is to override the `NSUserDefaults` language key before `UIApplicationMain()` is called in your `main()` function in main.m. Try something like this in your `main()` function:

```
// use whatever language/locale id you want to override
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"de_DE", nil]
                                          forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, nil);
```

Comment: @TimurMustafaev Give him 100$  ;-)