# How do I get the language that an iphone's user is currently seeing in my app?

Tags: iphone, localization, internationalization

I can get the user's language preferences by looking at `[NSLocale preferredLanguages]`.  But if I offer 'en' and 'fr' translations, and the user's preferences are 'en-GB', 'de', 'fr', 'en' will they see my 'en' or my 'fr' translation?  How do I get the language that the user is currently seeing in my app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to see which of your localizations is being used, store a string in your strings file describing it ("en", "fr" or whatever) and then load it with NSLocalizedString.

Comment: +1, clever workaround! Although be aware that your localizers might not understand why they are asked to translate "en" and might get the translation completely wrong as a result, so you'd need to remember to check this particular string carefully if you have a localization workflow.

Comment: You could always add it at the build stage using a script negating the need to manually manage it.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Doesn't that give me the language they see on the home screen?  I'm trying to find the language they see in my app.

Comment: See this post as it describes methods for allowing in-app language preferences and switching: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920

Answer (score 0):

Multiple people claim the right way to do this would be:

```
NSArray *languages = [NSLocale preferredLanguages];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];
```

Use at your own risk, though. [`NSLocale`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html) docs don't mention anything about first element being the current one.

Comment: Yeah - that's my question.  How do I get the current one?