# Storing key/value pair in Strings files

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Currently the way I store strings is by using Localizable.strings, 
for example

English:

```
"URL" = "http://google.com";
```

Spanish:

```
"URL" = "http://google.com";
```

As you can see I have the same string for both languages, is there a way I can use something similar to localizable.strings (loads automatically, compatible with any language/localization) without having to write the same key/value in both files? And then retrieve the value using a method? ( NSGetstring("URL") )

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language - this may help you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can store the key/value pairs in a plist and read that into your code. Like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSString *finalPath = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myList.plist"];
plistDictionary = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:finalPath] retain];
```

Just store your information in the plist, then access it like you would any other dicitonary item:

```
NSLog(@"URL: %@", [plistDictionary objectForKey:@"URL"]);
```

Comment: Yea.. but is there a way I can do it automatically without having to specify the path and storing it in a dict?

Comment: The only way I can think of doing it without specifying a path is to use the NSUserDefaults, but that'd still require a dict :P

Comment: ok thx, I will leave the question open, maybe others may have an alternative :S