# how safe it is to change AppleLanguages property

Tags: iphone, ios, localization

i am planning to do this in my app, that is to change the vlaue of the appleLanguage key in the userdefaults.

[How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

2 questions
1. will this not affect the inbuilt core ? will it keep it intact ? will it not affect other apps running on the same phone ?
2. what will happen to the apps which is build on top of these value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you are linking to is based on `NSUserDefaults` which is unique to the app. So it will only affect your own app, and nothing else.

Comment: Thanks @clafou. For records i have tested it on a 3gs device and it works as you explained. No change to the values on the other app.