# Multilanguage Application in Iphone

Tags: iphone, localization, arabic

How do I change my applications default language within my application? I am trying to change my applications language to Arabic, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

Comment: You can find answer here,
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way:

First make a different folder named as `ar.lproj` and put `localizable.String`

May following sample code help you. You can call this function in `viewWillAppear` with the key for which you need to get value.

```
-(NSString*) languageSelectedStringForKey:(NSString*) key
{

   NSString *path;
   NSUserDefaults *userDefault = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
  if([[userDefault valueForKey:@"language_Selected"] intValue] == 0)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"];

  else if([[userDefault valueForKey:@"language_Selected"] intValue] == 1)
  path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ar" ofType:@"lproj"];

  NSBundle* languageBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
  NSString* str=[[languageBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil] retain];
  return str;
}
```

Hope you will understand the concept.