# Build a FIXED language version for my already localized app in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, localization

My app already supports localization in English and French with custom images and .strings.
But how can I build and archive a version of my app that is fixed to just English or just French without having to manually change my images and .strings file?

So it doesn't matter what language the user has on his or her phone, the app must remain in that fixed language.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can remove localization languages from your XCode target settings without removing the actual files. See the answer to this related question: [Force a specific localization to be used for a target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10486374/force-a-specific-localization-to-be-used-for-a-target/10495375#10495375)

Comment: Thanks! It almost worked. Xcode allowed me to remove French but not English because it was default. I then experimented a little and I did find a way around it. I copied the French Localized.strings into en.lproj folder replacing the original one and the app stayed French!