# How can I change language and locale of only my application programmatically

Tags: objective-c, macos, locale

I want to change language and locale of my application alone to a language different than user's default that is set on the system. Say my application should use resources of french even though the system default is set to English.

I found few examples for iOS ([How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)) but even this is only for language, but nothing for OSX. I have the french resource in my bundle. I just want to override the defaults for my application alone. Without changing the entire OS locale from system preferences.

Answer (score 0):

There are nice apps for this problem: [Language Switcher](http://www.tj-hd.co.uk/en-gb/languageswitcher/) and [App Language Chooser](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/app-language-chooser/id451732904) to name a few.

To do it programmatically, you can use the `defaults` command to change the app's `AppleLanguages` property to `(fr)` or `(en, ko)`, as the following shell script:

```sh
bundleId=BUNDLE_ID_OF_YOUR_APP  # such as, com.apple.Finder
# change AppleLanguages
defaults write $bundleId AppleLanguages "(fr)"
# open your app
open -b $bundleId
# then restore the language
defaults delete $bundleId AppleLanguages
```

See the answer to this similar question at superuser for more detail: [Can I change the default language of a application / program in Snow Leopard?](https://superuser.com/a/46301/45702).