# IOS , How to force the Locale to one Language

Tags: ios, objective-c

Now I am currently developing a app. I want set this app to a default Language like Chinese. It means that no matter how the system Locale set,like English or Japanese.It will always show the Chinese. Is there a way to set by code?

Comment: Do all of your app with Chiness and don't add any localization to it.

Answer (score 1):

Inside the info.plist, set the `Localization native development region (CFBundleDevelopmentRegion)` to Chinese and do not localize files.

Your app will be only in chinese and will appear like chinese on iTunes

Answer (score 0):

The App must be in the "Ready for Sale" state on iTunes Connect.

1) Go to your list of apps
2) Open the desired app
3) Click "Edit" on "App Information"
4) Set the Default Language and save

Comment: Is there a way that I can set by objective code or at Plist file?

Comment: Not as far as I know, but with multiple xib files or storyboards perhaps, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12192151/change-app-language-in-ios-without-restarting-the-app