# iOS app is not being localized as per selected language

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization, nsuserdefaults

I have localized my app using the localization feature in iOS, I have added Localizable.strings files (English and Spanish) in my project.

So far the app was behaving nicely, found the following issue

After a while when switching the device/simulator to spanish the app is still in english or vice versa. I have been logging the following

```
NSLog(@"Preferred Language : %@", [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0]);
NSLog(@"Locale Identifier : %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"NSUserDefaults AppleLanguages : %@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"]);
```

Before the app reaches to this issue has the following output

```
Preferred Language : en
Locale Identifier : en_US
NSUserDefaults AppleLanguages : (
en,
es,
de,
fr,
ja,
nl,
it,
pt,
"pt-PT",
da,
fi,
nb,
sv,
ko,
"zh-Hans",
"zh-Hant",
ru,
pl,
tr,
uk,
ar,
hr,
cs,
el,
he,
ro,
sk,
th,
id,
ms,
"en-GB",
ca,
hu,
vi
)
```

then after a while (even if I have switched successfully the language) when switching again the app to spanish the `AppleLanguages` array in `NSUserDefaults` has only one language, in this case english (en).

```
Preferred Language : en
Locale Identifier : en_US
NSUserDefaults AppleLanguages : (
en
)
```

This is causing the app to be displayed per the only preferred language which is the first element in the `AppleLanguages` array.
So far I'm not changing or modifying the `AppleLanguages` array in `NSUserDefaults` anywhere in the code. The only thing I'm forcing is to load the english `bundle` for the `Localizable.string` file with the following code

```
NSBundle *englishBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"en" ofType:@"lproj"]]; 
NSString *localizedString = NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"Key to localize", nil, englishBundle, @"");
```

I commented this code thinking that probably was messing the `NSUserDefaults AppleLanguages` array but the issue persist. I wonder what exactly is causing this issue or if probably I'm missing something in the project configuration.

**EDIT (1)**

So far I have found that the `Info.plist` file that stores the `NSUserDefaults` properties for the app, for some reason is saving the `AppleLanguages` with just one language item regardless that in the entire code I'm not overriding the `AppleLanguages` array.

Temporally I have added the following code in `applicationDidEnterBackground`

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setObject:nil forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
```

By doing the workaround above I have forced the app to always remove the `AppleLanguages` from the `Info.plist` file, so far I have found that this issue is only happened in `iOS 7.0` to `iOS 7.02`, I'm still testing in different iOS versions, I don't want to assume that this is an iOS bug but probably a misconfiguration in my project that so far I have not been able to identify or reproduce.

Comment: This might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12193507/400544

Answer (score 0):

Maybe after changing the language to Spanish, you need to restart the app.

Comment: App is being restarted automatically when changing the language.

Answer (score 0):

I have this code in one of my projects:

```
NSString* localizedStringFromBundle(NSString *key)
{
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *localeCode = [[NSLocale autoupdatingCurrentLocale] localeIdentifier];
    NSString *languageCode = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode];
    NSString *localizedString = key;
    BOOL found = NO;
    if ([[bundle localizations] indexOfObject:languageCode] == NSNotFound &&
        [[bundle localizations] indexOfObject:localeCode] == NSNotFound)
    {
        return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:@"en.lproj/Localizable"];
    }

    if ([[bundle localizations] indexOfObject:localeCode] != NSNotFound)
    {
        NSString *translationTableName = [localeCode stringByAppendingString:@".lproj/Localizable"];
        localizedString = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:translationTableName];
        found = ![localizedString isEqualToString:key];
    }

    if (!found)
    {
        NSString *translationTableName = [languageCode stringByAppendingString:@".lproj/Localizable"];
        localizedString = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:translationTableName];
        if ([localizedString isEqualToString:key])
        {
            localizedString = [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:nil table:@"en.lproj/Localizable"];
        }
        else
            NSLog(@"Missing string for key: %@, returning string: %@", key, localizedString);
    }
    return localizedString;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but noticed that your solution is using the `currentLocale` instead the `preferredLanguages` I think the right approach is to localize the app by using the user preferred language and for number formatting use the region/locale.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13 or newer, the language selection can be made on a "per app" based via the Settings app.

[New features available with iOS 13:](https://web.archive.org/web/20200815085807/https://www.apple.com/ios/ios-13/features/)

> **Language selection per app**
>
> Use third‑party apps in a different language from your system language.