# Nslocaliazation and nsinternationalization

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5

I have 3 languages in tableview in ios. If user select any language, nib file  change automaticaaly according to that language,How should i do it??

Comment: where u put three languages ?? on row of table >> ??

Comment: yes i have 3 row in table

Comment: have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/1746920#1746920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a language class like this:

```
@implementation Language

static NSBundle *bundle = nil;

+(void)initialize {
 NSUserDefaults* defs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
 NSArray* languages = [defs objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
 NSString *current = [[languages objectAtIndex:0] retain];
 [self setLanguage:current];

}

/*
  example calls:
  [Language setLanguage:@"it"];
  [Language setLanguage:@"de"];
*/
+(void)setLanguage:(NSString *)l {
 NSLog(@"preferredLang: %@", l);
 NSString *path = [[ NSBundle mainBundle ] pathForResource:l ofType:@"lproj" ];
 bundle = [[NSBundle bundleWithPath:path] retain];
}

+(NSString *)get:(NSString *)key alter:(NSString *)alternate {
 return [bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:alternate table:nil];
}

@end
```

Then have a function in the viewcontroller that you implement the tableview and you can have a dropdown menu using a pickerview:

```
- (NSInteger)selectedRowInComponent:(NSInteger)component{
    if (component == 0)
    {
      [Language setLanguage:@"de"];
    }
    if (component == 1)
    {
       [Language setLanguage:@"it"];
    }
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Create three `UIViewController` such like, 
VC1, VC2, VC3 and put `.h file` of all three (*UIViewController*) in your `mainVC.m` (*Here **mainVC** is `UITableView` Containing `UIViewController`* ) such like,

```
#import "VC1.h"
#import "VC2.h"
#import "VC3.h"
```

and use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method of `UITableView`

```
#pragma mark - UITableView Delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        VC1 *ob1 = [[VC1 alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:ob1 animated:YES];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        VC2 *ob2 = [[VC2 alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:ob2 animated:YES];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
        VC3 *ob3 = [[VC3 alloc] init];
        [self presentModalViewController:ob3 animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.You can use three nib files as below for same ViewController or you can use three ViewController with three nibs.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        HomeViewController * objHome            =   [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Write your 1 nib name here" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController :objHome animated:NO];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        HomeViewController * objHome            =   [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Write your 2 nib name here" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController :objHome animated:NO];
    }
    if (indexPath.row == 2)
    {
       HomeViewController * objHome            =   [[HomeViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"Write your 3 nib name here" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController :objHome animated:NO];
    }

}
```

Please dont forget to release the object if you are not using ARC.