# Change application specific language through programming without restarting iOS app

Tags: ios

I have requirement like below:
In my application I have provided list for language. Now when user change language then it should change all Titles and messages to particular language. Actual flow is like, I have one Screen (view) for setting in my app. In that setting screen I have provided language option.Now when user select language then in my application all Titles, Messages should get displayed in selected language without starting my app.

Now issue is when I select language for example Spanish then it is not taking effect without restarting my app. I have used function as given below:

```
-(void) SetUserLanguage
{
    NSString *appDataFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"UserLanguageList" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSDictionary *appDataDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:appDataFilePath];
    NSString* langName = [appDataDictionary objectForKey:self.pstrUserLanguage];
    if(langName == nil || [langName isEqualToString:@""])
    {
        langName = @"en";
    }
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSArray *langArray = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    NSArray *currentLangArray = [NSArray arrayWithObject:langName];
    [defaults setObject:currentLangArray forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}
```

above function is part of one interface called UserDataManager and instance of that is available globally for application using gpUserDataManager. So on selection of language I set language to this structure and then I have my predefined plist file for mapping.So when user select language Spanish it set value "es" to preferred language in above function. But to have effect of this change I need to restart my app. Kindly help how to achieve my requirement.

Comment: Note that for setting titles and display message I have used NSLocalizedString function.

Answer (score 2):

[TSLanguageManager](https://github.com/tonisalae/TSLanguageManager) will let you do what you ask. The usage is really simple;

When you want to change the language like by tapping a UIButton, just use the following code to change the language;

```
[TSLanguageManager setSelectedLanguage:kLMEnglish];
```

To change the text according to the new language,

```
yourTextField.text = [TSLanguageManager localizedString:@"yourLocalizedString"];
```

Please note that you need to keep all the localized strings in Localizable.strings file.

Comment: It´s ok for me. Only say than in iOS7  [userDefaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"] return  "es"  and in iOS9 return "es-ES" and it´s necessary to control in TSLanguageManager:selectedLanguage

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid restarting your app, take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7933427/1298263).

You basically need to use a different bundle, so use `NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle` instead of `NSLocalizedString` macro, and give it the correct bundle for the language chosen.