# Is there a way to get array of all possible keyboards

Tags: ios, keyboard, uikeyboard

I'm working on dictionary and trying to give user possibility to choose keyboard he gonna use. Is there a way to get array of system keyboards just like in **Settings>General>Keyboard>Keyboards>Add New Keyboard...** ?

Answer (score 0):

Question wasn't correct at all. There's no need in getting list, because there's no way to change keyboard language programatically. Instead founded this solution:
[Change Language in the app programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061402/change-language-in-the-app-programmatically)

And here is list of languages suppored in IOS:
http://www.ibabbleon.com/iOS-Language-Codes-ISO-639.html