# How to reset the value of "AppleLanguages" key in UserDefaults

Tags: swift, swiftyuserdefaults

Initially, I have saved the value of 'AppleLanguages' key as 'en', and then when I tried to change the value as 'ar', but it still remains as 'en'

I tried to clear the value to clearing the entire UserDefaults by uninstalling the application from the device, but no luck

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["ar"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```

I expect the result to be 'ar', but the result i get is 'en'

Comment: When you change the language of your app you have to kill the app and restart it again, otherwise, it won't get change.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749459/setting-applelanguages-doesnt-change-app-language

Comment: You need to change your bundle also.

Comment: .synchronize() is obsolete, useless and can even cause issues. The docs explain why. Please never use it.

Comment: As far as I know English is required to be in the list of preferred languages.

Answer (score 2):

Hi Use below code to reset to default

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(["Base"], forKey: "AppleLanguages")
UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
```