# How to have 2 languages on debug and only 1 on productio?

Tags: ios, localization

On the app that I develop I want to have english and greek in debug mode (because I don't speak greek and the app is for Greece) and only Greek when when in release( because I have a requirement to only support Greek and no english when the app is released).

So, does anyone know how can I do this in iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After all I inspired a little from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749459/setting-applelanguages-doesnt-change-app-language) thread, more exactly [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38429383/4915700) answer.

And here is how my solution looks:

Removed `@UIApplicationMain` from `AppDelegate` and created `main.swift` and added this code:

```
if !SharedConstants.isDebugEnabled {
    let supportedLanguages: [String] = ["el"]
    UserDefaults.standard.set(supportedLanguages, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
    UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
UIApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv, nil, NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))
```

LATER EDIT:

Later I found the solution to add the below script in `Build Phases` to remove the english language and I don't need any of the workarounds above.

```
if [ $CONFIGURATION == 'Release' ]; then
    rm -r "${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/en.lproj"
fi;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution 1**

One easy thing I would do :

- Create a new branch for production
- Remove the English language in the project while keeping the files

Now every time you merge into prod, it will be up-to-date without the English language available.
NB: Don't forget to switch back to your dev branch while you are coding!

**Solution 2**

If you can't use another branch, you can create a Build Run Script that will get executed every time you build the app and/or use Fastlane to customise your deployment pipeline

Comment: I also suggested this solution, but automated build for end to end testing should also be only in english and that is done from the same branch we do development and sadly I don't think I can use this solution, but I will keep it as a backup

Comment: Maybe you should create your own Build Run Script to clean whatever you need to clean