# How to change the layout of an iOS app programmatically from LTR to RTL and vice versa?

Tags: ios, localization, right-to-left

So, I tried changing the app language programmatically from `English` to an `RTL` language. The text is localized but the layout is still `LTR` until I restart the app that `RTL` takes effect.

Is there a way to make this happen without restarting the app?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41140436/6203030

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up forcing RTL in runtime using the `setSemanticContentAttribute` method like bellow:

```
if ([NSLocale characterDirectionForLanguage:languageCode] == NSLocaleLanguageDirectionRightToLeft) {
    if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:
         UISemanticContentAttributeForceRightToLeft];
    }
}
else {
    if ([[[UIView alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setSemanticContentAttribute:)]) {
        [[UIView appearance] setSemanticContentAttribute:UISemanticContentAttributeForceLeftToRight];
    }
}
```