# iOS How to synchronize Main.storyboard strings and Localizable.strings

Tags: ios, swift, localizable.strings

So, i have rally big issues.

First of all, i have 2 Localizable files, first it's Main.storyboard where i translate all labels, buttons.

And i have Localizable.strings where i translate error message, and some system message.

And i have something like this:

[image]

Translation working OK if i setup phone language.

But if i want to change manually language from the app, only translating file **Localizable.strings**.

Maybe it's possible to synchronize this two file in one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985614/how-can-i-change-locale-programmatically-with-swift

Comment: As commented below do not that. Apple’s localization works with the system language.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change "AppleLanguages".

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
defaults.setObject("rs", forKey: "AppleLanguages")
```

Comment: And it's will get translation from 2 file?

Comment: Yes, PLease try it.

Comment: Apple recommend that you do _not_ do this… _"You're going to be swimming up stream if you attempt this.  If you stomp on the AppleLanguages then various things won't behave as they normally would.  Your app's user interface won't automatically flip you layout to be RTL, locale settings used for formatters won't be affected, and other things.  You're going to be fighting a losing battle here so I'd strongly recommend you not go this route."_ https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/8674

Comment: You can change UIView appearance using below the line.
UIView.appearance().semanticContentAttribute = .forceRightToLeft