# How to change the language and update content programatically inside the application, not from phone? IOS swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, nslocalizedstring

I'm trying to build an app, from where user can select the language and i want to change the content of whole application. For example i have two labels and two languages english and german. two files of Localizable (en , de). on my screen user press turn to german and i want to change the language of the application and want to update the UI but i dont want to the user to close the application. I found some of solution over here but that didn't work out like [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985614/how-can-i-change-locale-programmatically-with-swift)

```
extension Bundle {
private static var bundle: Bundle!

public static func localizedBundle() -> Bundle! {
    if bundle == nil {
        let appLang = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "app_lang") ?? "ru"
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: appLang, ofType: "lproj")
        bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
    }

    return bundle;
}

public static func setLanguage(lang: String) {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(lang, forKey: "app_lang")
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: lang, ofType: "lproj")
    bundle = Bundle(path: path!)
}}
```

and this

```
extension String {
func localized() -> String {
    return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: Bundle.localizedBundle(), value: "", comment: "")
}

func localizeWithFormat(arguments: CVarArg...) -> String{
    return String(format: self.localized(), arguments: arguments)
}}
```

and using it like

```
@IBAction func englishAction(_ sender: Any) {
    let  localisedSt = "en".localized()
    Bundle.setLanguage(lang: "en")
}
```

after this i tried to reload app , reload view but nothing change.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLocalizedString` will look up inside the localization table appropriate for the application which is determined by device or `UserDefaults`. There is a custom key that you can set inside `UserDefaults` and determine what language you're wishing to use, then on the next launch of the application it will load the appropriate bundle.

If you want to change localization **inside** the application(on the fly), you need to lookup the table manually from `Bundle` representing that `Locale`. Just look for the file with extension `.lproj` and recreate another `Bundle` with fetched path, and query generated `Bundle` for localized string.

```swift
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en");
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: locale.identifier, ofType: "lproj") 
else { return };
let localizedBundle = Bundle(path: path)
localizedBundle.localizedString(forKey:_, value:_, table:_) // you can pass NULL in table to look into "Localizable.strings"
```

But of-course, after changing the locale, you also need to update all currently configured texts.

I wrote a library called [Styled](https://github.com/farzadshbfn/Styled) that can help you with that part (that and also Interpolation, Color/Font synchronization with device font system)