# Not able to update Localizable.strings file dynamically

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I have localization in my app for French language which I have implemented like so...

I have a file called `Localizable.strings(French)` which contains all the French keywords given like so...

```
"Hello" = "Bonjour";
"Tree" = "Arbre";
"Sun" = "soleil";
```

And if I want to localize a particular label, I do it like so...

`myLabel.text = "Hello".localized`

Now say I get some keywords like these from an API :

```
   "Moon" = "Lune”;    
   "car" = "auto”;
```

How can I update my `Localizable.strings(French)` file with these keywords programatically without having to go and manually enter the keywords I get from the API..?

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29985614/how-can-i-change-locale-programmatically-with-swift) link and also looked up other similar answers in SO..but couldn't get a solution yet...