# How to add custom fonts in settings.bundle in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to implement custom fonts in ios settings.bundle file.if user selects custom font in my application then automatically change the font in my app.so i am trying to create settings.bundle. but i cant get custom font in settings.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lx6Sg.png)

but i want to display like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POjpO.png)

please help me any body.i am writing code like this.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

// Override point for customization after application launch.

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[defaults setValue:@"0.0.1" forKey:@"languageoption"];

[defaults synchronize];

return YES;

}
```

Comment: do you want to switch languages or change the font for the same language?

Comment: i want to switch the language.. means i want to display telugu font in my application when user click the telugu font family through my application

Comment: You don't have to switch fonts to change the language. The Unicode standard supports almost all languages.

Comment: i need to customize my font family in settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your intention is to support multiple languages in your app, there is no need to have multiple fonts, you can enable localization in your project and then its as simple as :

> "Hello World" = "హలో వరల్డ్"

Check out [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014) for a detailed explanation. Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22061784/3894781).

*Note:* its a hack but you can use an available language like arabic, and then provide Telugu strings as translations. and follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1746920/3894781) answer to change your language on the fly.

Comment: but my requirement is user want to change font family then user go to settings page and select required language. this is my requirement. so in settings ios does not provide telugu language feature

Comment: ShahiM i can understand what u r saying.. but my doubt if user wants to switch the language from english to telugu in settings. But in settings page there is no telugu language option. then how does user switch from english to telugu??

Comment: check out the second link in my answer. there is a method to implement your own language selection logic.

Answer (score 0):

Telugu is supported by iOS. You can find this information following [this link](http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/English_list.php) given by Apple itself [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LanguageandLocaleIDs/LanguageandLocaleIDs.html).

But you have to custom all of this by yourself, by adding an NSArray of all languages supported by your app in the Settings.bundle, to allow the user to choose the app language, and being able to load the good font depending on the language choosen by the user.