# Changing Locale within the app itself in IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, localization, xcode6

I have an IOS APP with need to be run in both Arabic and English version.
I need to switch the languages within a settings menu in APP.

Some What like this[image]

I can change all the strings using NSBundle, or plist like any other language switching.

But as every one knows, English is a left to right language and arabic is just opposite. then i add app localization by default in IOS but i didnt get the exact solution what i asked.
I have gone through this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/LocalizingYourApp/LocalizingYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i-CH5-SW1

Can anyone help me?? it will be very great..

Thanks in Advance.. :)

Comment: Why do you want to do it in the app instead of using system settings?

Comment: It is client requirement man... :)

Comment: Often we are here to educate and guide clients

Comment: But they already have an application with multi language. i don't know how it works!! so they have any excuse for not doing the same in these app too.. !!!

Comment: I obviously don't exactly understand what it is you are asking or what the problem is, because there appears to be existing answers for this already. How does what you want to do differ from this for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061402/change-language-in-the-app-programmatically