# Unable to set primary language in custom keyboard extension

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-keyboard-extension

Why primary language returns null in custom keyboard and how can i change it for support multiple languages.

```
<key>NSExtension</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExtensionAttributes</key>
        <dict>
            <key>IsASCIICapable</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PrefersRightToLeft</key>
            <false/>
            <key>PrimaryLanguage</key>
            <string>mul</string>
            <key>RequestsOpenAccess</key>
            <false/>
        </dict>
```

I want to set primary language programmatically acc to user selection from container app.
Any Suggestion for this.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's iOS 8.1 Simulator's bugs.

I could tested language by setting the "Application Language" in the used scheme.

Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme... or press cmd + Y.

[image]

Comment: how to set programatically means at run time

Comment: i want to change this thing for rchange the alignment also

Comment: check these link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12595970/iphone-change-keyboard-language-programmatically and this one also  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061402/change-language-in-the-app-programmatically