# Change language to system permission modals in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Apple didn't accept my application in the AppStore because the main language of my app is Spanish, but the modals that request permissions if the device is in English shows it in this language

They tell me that all my application must be in Spanish regardless of the language of the device.

I have already changed the development language to Spanish and it is still coming out in English. I have tried many ways, but not one has worked for me.

[Development language](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M6Srt.png)
[My app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIrYp.png)

Comment: It seems that you should implement localization for your app. Check out this article: https://medium.com/lean-localization/ios-localization-tutorial-938231f9f881 and this documentation: https://developer.apple.com/internationalization/

Comment: Welcome to SO! SO is about programming, and your question might be about programming, but this is not clear from your question. Thus, somebody has voted it down. I suggest that you read the [overview of SO](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), so that you can formulate your question better.

Comment: Use Custom Locale then your app will be not bound to current phone locale
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22061402/change-language-in-the-app-programmatically-in-ios

Comment: Did you find a way to solve this issue. I am stuck in exactly the same situation.