# I want to use urdu language as content in iOS App development.

Tags: ios, iphone, nslocalizedstring, nslocale

I am planning to make an app which will contain urdu and arabic text.

I dont want to use images for urdu language text, so I want to integrate some sort of urdu text Api.

Can anyone please let me know, that how I use urdu text in ios application in Xcode.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Urdu, does it use the Arabic character set?  If so, the normal internationalization/localization process should work.  In any case, Irfan's answer seems to indicate to me that the normal localization should work for Urdu.

Comment: Any luck doing it. Becuase I need the similar kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use Localization for this:

Here are some good tutorial you can follow :

**1)**  http://www.raywenderlich.com/2876/localization-tutorial-for-ios

**2)**  http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-localization-apps/

And here is the list of avaliableLocalIdentifiers with the english locale description,
taken from iPod touch iOS 6.0.1.

I do not believe that all these are supported for localisation!

```
en_IE - English (Ireland)

ro_MD - Romanian (Moldova)

br - Breton

en_GY - English (Guyana)

es_GT - Spanish (Guatemala)

shi_Tfng_MA - Tachelhit (Tifinagh, Morocco)

mr - Marathi

bs - Bosnian

en_AS - English (American Samoa)

ksf - Bafia

sr_Latn_ME - Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)

ms - Malay

ms_MY - Malay (Malaysia)

mt - Maltese

ha - Hausa

nb_NO - Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)

en_BZ - English (Belize)

pt_BR - Portuguese (Brazil)

or_IN - Oriya (India)

is_IS - Icelandic (Iceland)

mn_Cyrl_MN - Mongolian (Cyrillic, Mongolia)

ar_IQ - Arabic (Iraq)

he - Hebrew

zh_Hans_CN - Chinese (Simplified, China)

my - Burmese

bas - Basaa

mer - Meru

en_JM - English (Jamaica)

dz_BT - Dzongkha (Bhutan)

teo_KE - Teso (Kenya)

cy_GB - Welsh (United Kingdom)

sg - Sango

it_CH - Italian (Switzerland)

de_LU - German (Luxembourg)

en_US - English (United States)

hi - Hindi

hu_HU - Hungarian (Hungary)

uz_Latn_UZ - Uzbek (Latin, Uzbekistan)

af_NA - Afrikaans (Namibia)

si - Sinhala

fr_BI - French (Burundi)

ga_IE - Irish (Ireland)

mfe - Morisyen

en_CA - English (Canada)

ne_IN - Nepali (India)

rwk_TZ - Rwa (Tanzania)

en_AU - English (Australia)

sk - Slovak

teo - Teso

sl - Slovenian

tk_Latn_TM - Turkmen (Latin, Turkmenistan)

tzm_Latn - Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin)

ee_GH - Ewe (Ghana)

kde - Makonde

sn - Shona

dyo_SN - Jola-Fonyi (Senegal)

mas_TZ - Masai (Tanzania)

en_SG - English (Singapore)

so - Somali

nyn_UG - Nyankole (Uganda)

br_FR - Breton (France)

fr_BJ - French (Benin)

pt_MZ - Portuguese (Mozambique)

hr - Croatian

az_Latn - Azerbaijani (Latin)

sq - Albanian

sr - Serbian

sw_KE - Swahili (Kenya)

ca - Catalan

hu - Hungarian

et_EE - Estonian (Estonia)

lag_TZ - Langi (Tanzania)

nb - Norwegian Bokmål

bn_IN - Bengali (India)

sv - Swedish

th_TH - Thai (Thailand)

ml_IN - Malayalam (India)

sr_Cyrl_RS - Serbian (Cyrillic, Serbia)

sw - Swahili

nd - North Ndebele

ta_IN - Tamil (India)

fr_MQ - French (Martinique)

hy - Armenian

ne - Nepali

es_AR - Spanish (Argentina)

pt_AO - Portuguese (Angola)

ne_NP - Nepali (Nepal)

ar_BH - Arabic (Bahrain)

hi_IN - Hindi (India)

bo_IN - Tibetan (India)

seh - Sena

de_DE - German (Germany)

fr_BL - French (Saint Barthélemy)

fr_MR - French (Mauritania)

fa_IR - Persian (Iran)

nl - Dutch

es_PR - Spanish (Puerto Rico)

en_PW - English (Palau)

rn_BI - Rundi (Burundi)

nn - Norwegian Nynorsk

kk_Cyrl - Kazakh (Cyrillic)

sl_SI - Slovenian (Slovenia)

dua - Duala

kea - Kabuverdianu

ig_NG - Igbo (Nigeria)

kln - Kalenjin

yo - Yoruba

sv_FI - Swedish (Finland)

ru_MD - Russian (Moldova)

en_ZW - English (Zimbabwe)

brx_IN - Bodo (India)

fil_PH - Filipino (Philippines)

cs - Czech

pt_GW - Portuguese (Guinea-Bissau)

bn_BD - Bengali (Bangladesh)

de_AT - German (Austria)

luo - Luo

sk_SK - Slovak (Slovakia)

ar_001 - Arabic (World)

es_US - Spanish (United States)

ta - Tamil

mk_MK - Macedonian (Macedonia)

om_KE - Oromo (Kenya)

da_DK - Danish (Denmark)

ko_KR - Korean (South Korea)

shi_Latn - Tachelhit (Latin)

ff_SN - Fulah (Senegal)

id - Indonesian

sr_Cyrl_ME - Serbian (Cyrillic, Montenegro)

kde_TZ - Makonde (Tanzania)

cy - Welsh

mgh - Makhuwa-Meetto

te - Telugu

fr_GN - French (Guinea)

fo_FO - Faroese (Faroe Islands)

ig - Igbo

it_IT - Italian (Italy)

uk_UA - Ukrainian (Ukraine)

tg - Tajik

vai - Vai

bm_ML - Bambara (Mali)

en_SL - English (Sierra Leone)

ii - Sichuan Yi

ses - Koyraboro Senni

th - Thai

ti - Tigrinya

ru_KZ - Russian (Kazakhstan)

te_IN - Telugu (India)

tk - Turkmen

cs_CZ - Czech (Czech Republic)

ar_AE - Arabic (United Arab Emirates)

brx - Bodo

haw - Hawaiian

tzm_Latn_MA - Central Morocco Tamazight (Latin, Morocco)

so_DJ - Somali (Djibouti)

uz_Cyrl_UZ - Uzbek (Cyrillic, Uzbekistan)

to - Tongan

ewo_CM - Ewondo (Cameroon)

nl_AW - Dutch (Aruba)

ar_MR - Arabic (Mauritania)

sn_ZW - Shona (Zimbabwe)

en_IN - English (India)

en_TT - English (Trinidad and Tobago)

tr - Turkish

is - Icelandic

fr_GP - French (Guadeloupe)

luy - Luyia

es_NI - Spanish (Nicaragua)

it - Italian

da - Danish

kln_KE - Kalenjin (Kenya)

tk_Latn - Turkmen (Latin)

en_BB - English (Barbados)

ar_DZ - Arabic (Algeria)

ar_SY - Arabic (Syria)

ha_Latn - Hausa (Latin)

en_MH - English (Marshall Islands)

mr_IN - Marathi (India)

en_GB - English (United Kingdom)

de - German

fr_GQ - French (Equatorial Guinea)

ky_KG - Kirghiz (Kyrgyzstan)

pt_PT - Portuguese (Portugal)

fr_RW - French (Rwanda)

nus_SD - Nuer (Sudan)

asa - Asu

zh - Chinese

ha_Latn_GH - Hausa (Latin, Ghana)

bo_CN - Tibetan (China)

kam_KE - Kamba (Kenya)

dua_CM - Duala (Cameroon)

khq_ML - Koyra Chiini (Mali)

ur_IN - Urdu (India)

ro_RO - Romanian (Romania)

om - Oromo

ksb_TZ - Shambala (Tanzania)

gu_IN - Gujarati (India)

fr_TD - French (Chad)

jmc - Machame

ja_JP - Japanese (Japan)

so_ET - Somali (Ethiopia)

nl_NL - Dutch (Netherlands)

es_ES - Spanish (Spain)

or - Oriya

yo_NG - Yoruba (Nigeria)

es_PY - Spanish (Paraguay)

mua_CM - Mundang (Cameroon)

fa_AF - Persian (Afghanistan)

en_HK - English (Hong Kong SAR China)

luo_KE - Luo (Kenya)

ja - Japanese

twq - Tasawaq

en_BE - English (Belgium)

es_UY - Spanish (Uruguay)

dje_NE - Zarma (Niger)

luy_KE - Luyia (Kenya)

naq - Nama

si_LK - Sinhala (Sri Lanka)

zu - Zulu

bs_BA - Bosnian (Bosnia and Herzegovina)

zh_Hans_MO - Chinese (Simplified, Macau SAR China)

fr_KM - French (Comoros)

zh_Hant_HK - Chinese (Traditional, Hong Kong SAR China)

dz - Dzongkha

swc - Congo Swahili

asa_TZ - Asu (Tanzania)

az_Cyrl - Azerbaijani (Cyrillic)

ewo - Ewondo

gv_GB - Manx (United Kingdom)

ti_ER - Tigrinya (Eritrea)

be_BY - Belarusian (Belarus)

uk - Ukrainian

nyn - Nyankole

cgg_UG - Chiga (Uganda)

de_CH - German (Switzerland)

fr_TG - French (Togo)

jmc_TZ - Machame (Tanzania)

ta_LK - Tamil (Sri Lanka)

so_SO - Somali (Somalia)

es_DO - Spanish (Dominican Republic)

fr_LU - French (Luxembourg)

shi_Latn_MA - Tachelhit (Latin, Morocco)

swc_CD - Congo Swahili (Congo - Kinshasa)

kn_IN - Kannada (India)

hy_AM - Armenian (Armenia)

fil - Filipino

bas_CM - Basaa (Cameroon)

ar_TD - Arabic (Chad)

ur - Urdu

bez_TZ - Bena (Tanzania)

haw_US - Hawaiian (United States)

tg_Cyrl - Tajik (Cyrillic)

pa - Punjabi

ee_TG - Ewe (Togo)

ti_ET - Tigrinya (Ethiopia)

sr_Latn_BA - Serbian (Latin, Bosnia and Herzegovina)

ee - Ewe

sv_SE - Swedish (Sweden)

ki_KE - Kikuyu (Kenya)

zh_Hans - Chinese (Simplified)

bem - Bemba

uz - Uzbek

ar_YE - Arabic (Yemen)

seh_MZ - Sena (Mozambique)

ru_UA - Russian (Ukraine)

fr_SC - French (Seychelles)

ar_KM - Arabic (Comoros)

en_ZA - English (South Africa)

nn_NO - Norwegian Nynorsk (Norway)

mas_KE - Masai (Kenya)

ar_EG - Arabic (Egypt)

el - Greek

pl - Polish

nl_BE - Dutch (Belgium)

en - English

uz_Latn - Uzbek (Latin)

eo - Esperanto

shi - Tachelhit

kok - Konkani

mas - Masai

fr_FR - French (France)

rof - Rombo

en_MP - English (Northern Mariana Islands)

de_BE - German (Belgium)

ar_EH - Arabic (Western Sahara)

es_CL - Spanish (Chile)

en_VI - English (U.S. Virgin Islands)

es - Spanish

ps - Pashto

et - Estonian

vai_Latn - Vai (Latin)

pt - Portuguese

eu - Basque

ka - Georgian

fr_NE - French (Niger)

eu_ES - Basque (Spain)

mgh_MZ - Makhuwa-Meetto (Mozambique)

zu_ZA - Zulu (South Africa)

ar_SA - Arabic (Saudi Arabia)

chr_US - Cherokee (United States)

cgg - Chiga

lag - Langi

az_Latn_AZ - Azerbaijani (Latin, Azerbaijan)

es_VE - Spanish (Venezuela)

el_GR - Greek (Greece)

el_CY - Greek (Cyprus)

mfe_MU - Morisyen (Mauritius)

ki - Kikuyu

vi - Vietnamese

rwk - Rwa

bez - Bena

kk - Kazakh

kl - Kalaallisut

zh_Hant - Chinese (Traditional)

fr_CA - French (Canada)

km - Khmer

es_HN - Spanish (Honduras)

agq_CM - Aghem (Cameroon)

kn - Kannada

ii_CN - Sichuan Yi (China)

mn_Cyrl - Mongolian (Cyrillic)

en_BM - English (Bermuda)

ko - Korean

ln_CD - Lingala (Congo - Kinshasa)

en_GM - English (Gambia)

es_CO - Spanish (Colombia)

guz_KE - Gusii (Kenya)

es_PA - Spanish (Panama)

twq_NE - Tasawaq (Niger)

en_NZ - English (New Zealand)

fa - Persian

en_US_POSIX - English (United States, Computer)

dav_KE - Taita (Kenya)

lt_LT - Lithuanian (Lithuania)

en_SZ - English (Swaziland)

ar_SD - Arabic (Sudan)

rof_TZ - Rombo (Tanzania)

uz_Arab_AF - Uzbek (Arabic, Afghanistan)

vi_VN - Vietnamese (Vietnam)

en_MT - English (Malta)

kw - Cornish

yav_CM - Yangben (Cameroon)

ta_MY - Tamil (Malaysia)

ru_KG - Russian (Kyrgyzstan)

kab - Kabyle

ky - Kirghiz

ff - Fulah

en_PG - English (Papua New Guinea)

to_TO - Tongan (Tonga)

ar_LY - Arabic (Libya)

af_ZA - Afrikaans (South Africa)

de_LI - German (Liechtenstein)

sr_Cyrl_BA - Serbian (Cyrillic, Bosnia and Herzegovina)

fi - Finnish

ksf_CM - Bafia (Cameroon)

khq - Koyra Chiini

gsw - Swiss German

es_SV - Spanish (El Salvador)

fr_DJ - French (Djibouti)

en_MU - English (Mauritius)

sr_Latn - Serbian (Latin)

pl_PL - Polish (Poland)

kea_CV - Kabuverdianu (Cape Verde)

pa_Arab - Punjabi (Arabic)

fr_MC - French (Monaco)

en_PH - English (Philippines)

saq - Samburu

ar_PS - Arabic (Palestinian Territories)

fr_CD - French (Congo - Kinshasa)

bem_ZM - Bemba (Zambia)

ru_RU - Russian (Russia)

uz_Cyrl - Uzbek (Cyrillic)

pa_Guru - Punjabi (Gurmukhi)

vai_Vaii - Vai (Vai)

fo - Faroese

so_KE - Somali (Kenya)

ln_CG - Lingala (Congo - Brazzaville)

ar_OM - Arabic (Oman)

pt_ST - Portuguese (São Tomé and Príncipe)

kl_GL - Kalaallisut (Greenland)

fr - French

es_CR - Spanish (Costa Rica)

ses_ML - Koyraboro Senni (Mali)

tzm - Central Morocco Tamazight

mer_KE - Meru (Kenya)

xog - Soga

xog_UG - Soga (Uganda)

nl_SX - Dutch (Sint Maarten)

en_FJ - English (Fiji)

en_MW - English (Malawi)

ar_MA - Arabic (Morocco)

kam - Kamba

am_ET - Amharic (Ethiopia)

af - Afrikaans

ar_TN - Arabic (Tunisia)

es_PE - Spanish (Peru)

sbp_TZ - Sangu (Tanzania)

fr_CF - French (Central African Republic)

vun_TZ - Vunjo (Tanzania)

lg - Ganda

ar_JO - Arabic (Jordan)

ebu - Embu

fr_RE - French (Réunion)

ha_Latn_NG - Hausa (Latin, Nigeria)

lv_LV - Latvian (Latvia)

ak - Akan

chr - Cherokee

az_Cyrl_AZ - Azerbaijani (Cyrillic, Azerbaijan)

dav - Taita

es_419 - Spanish (Latin America)

ebu_KE - Embu (Kenya)

fr_MF - French (Saint Martin)

am - Amharic

en_PK - English (Pakistan)

fr_CG - French (Congo - Brazzaville)

dje - Zarma

dyo - Jola-Fonyi

pa_Guru_IN - Punjabi (Gurmukhi, India)

ln - Lingala

ak_GH - Akan (Ghana)

ar_DJ - Arabic (Djibouti)

en_BS - English (Bahamas)

lo - Lao

zh_Hant_TW - Chinese (Traditional, Taiwan)

lg_UG - Ganda (Uganda)

ar_KW - Arabic (Kuwait)

ar - Arabic

fr_MG - French (Madagascar)

ca_ES - Catalan (Spain)

as - Assamese

he_IL - Hebrew (Israel)

sbp - Sangu

fr_GA - French (Gabon)

mg_MG - Malagasy (Madagascar)

my_MM - Burmese (Myanmar [Burma])

ps_AF - Pashto (Afghanistan)

fr_CH - French (Switzerland)

vun - Vunjo

lt - Lithuanian

kk_Cyrl_KZ - Kazakh (Cyrillic, Kazakhstan)

ga - Irish

en_FM - English (Micronesia)

lu - Luba-Katanga

nmg - Kwasio

es_BO - Spanish (Bolivia)

lv - Latvian

fr_YT - French (Mayotte)

km_KH - Khmer (Cambodia)

teo_UG - Teso (Uganda)

fr_SN - French (Senegal)

om_ET - Oromo (Ethiopia)

ms_BN - Malay (Brunei)

ar_ER - Arabic (Eritrea)

gsw_CH - Swiss German (Switzerland)

az - Azerbaijani

fi_FI - Finnish (Finland)

tr_TR - Turkish (Turkey)

fr_CI - French (Côte d’Ivoire)

en_UM - English (U.S. Minor Outlying Islands)

sr_Cyrl - Serbian (Cyrillic)

ur_PK - Urdu (Pakistan)

hr_HR - Croatian (Croatia)

nl_CW - Dutch (Curaçao)

nmg_CM - Kwasio (Cameroon)

en_GU - English (Guam)

es_EC - Spanish (Ecuador)

gl_ES - Galician (Spain)

zh_Hant_MO - Chinese (Traditional, Macau SAR China)

gl - Galician

mt_MT - Maltese (Malta)

ha_Latn_NE - Hausa (Latin, Niger)

en_NA - English (Namibia)

rm - Romansh

kw_GB - Cornish (United Kingdom)

zh_Hans_SG - Chinese (Simplified, Singapore)

rn - Rundi

ro - Romanian

rm_CH - Romansh (Switzerland)

saq_KE - Samburu (Kenya)

vai_Vaii_LR - Vai (Vai, Liberia)

ka_GE - Georgian (Georgia)

es_GQ - Spanish (Equatorial Guinea)

sr_Latn_RS - Serbian (Latin, Serbia)

zh_Hans_HK - Chinese (Simplified, Hong Kong SAR China)

agq - Aghem

gu - Gujarati

lo_LA - Lao (Laos)

ru - Russian

en_SB - English (Solomon Islands)

gv - Manx

en_BW - English (Botswana)

yav - Yangben

ta_SG - Tamil (Singapore)

fr_BE - French (Belgium)

bg_BG - Bulgarian (Bulgaria)

es_MX - Spanish (Mexico)

rw - Kinyarwanda

be - Belarusian

nd_ZW - North Ndebele (Zimbabwe)

mua - Mundang

kab_DZ - Kabyle (Algeria)

bg - Bulgarian

tg_Cyrl_TJ - Tajik (Cyrillic, Tajikistan)

mg - Malagasy

sg_CF - Sango (Central African Republic)

pa_Arab_PK - Punjabi (Arabic, Pakistan)

sw_TZ - Swahili (Tanzania)

en_SC - English (Seychelles)

nus - Nuer

shi_Tfng - Tachelhit (Tifinagh)

ar_QA - Arabic (Qatar)

naq_NA - Nama (Namibia)

fr_BF - French (Burkina Faso)

rw_RW - Kinyarwanda (Rwanda)

as_IN - Assamese (India)

guz - Gusii

ksb - Shambala

fr_ML - French (Mali)

mk - Macedonian

kok_IN - Konkani (India)

sq_AL - Albanian (Albania)

ml - Malayalam

fr_GF - French (French Guiana)

bm - Bambara

lu_CD - Luba-Katanga (Congo - Kinshasa)

fr_CM - French (Cameroon)

bn - Bengali

ar_LB - Arabic (Lebanon)

id_ID - Indonesian (Indonesia)

uz_Arab - Uzbek (Arabic)

mn - Mongolian

bo - Tibetan

vai_Latn_LR - Vai (Latin, Liberia)
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically just... do it. Apple's UI elements support the full range of Unicode, so they can show any Unicode characters. If the user has the appropriate keyboard turned on, they can enter those characters. Arabic and Urdu characters are included in Unicode and are supported as part of the iOS system font, and maybe others.

For example, this is just a regular `UITextField` with no custom settings, so it's showing text and not images (I don't know Arabic so I grabbed a few characters at random):

[image]

If you configure text fields, text views, etc, to use attributed strings you can also set the text direction as right-to-left, left-to-right, or "natural" (which I believe follows the user's language settings).

Comment: I dont want to use keyboard functionallity. I actually have a urdu book and want to convert it to a app. I just want some thing like store all book's text in database and thene retrieve in xcode.

Comment: Just store it in a text file and load that file into the app. Seriously, you do not need to do anything special.

Answer (score 0):

well here's the solution, there is an locale named `"ur"` it will localize your language to urdu, all you need is to localize your all .m files and .storyboard files,  try `genstrings`, first you need to goto root of your directory then in terminal enter this command

```
find ./ -name "*.m" -print0 | xargs -0 genstrings -o en.lproj
```

this will create a list of  .strings files add local language translations, create a page of settings or whatever, where you set the language,
you need to store that in app delegate, you can use this one for settings 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20257557/3265136

Answer (score 0):

Try using this steps :

Step 1: Download urdu.ttf font file from here [Download Urdu Font File](https://fonts2u.com/urdu.font)

Step 2: Include your fonts in your Xcode project like that image [Urdu-Font file in Xcode project Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EA6aP.png)

Step 3: Make sure that the font file included in the target

Step 4: Double check that your fonts are included as Resources in your bundle

Step 5: Finally use it like other fonts