# IOS Internalization MultiLanguage change by run time

Tags: ios, localization

I have an IOS app and i want to add multi language support. For Example; there are two button first for English and second for Dutch. If user presses the button English the app language change to English. The Dutch button for Dutch language. But there is some constraints. I search for many solutions.

1. I dont want to use the language option at Iphone "Settings"
2. The user wont restart the phone to see the changing language.

I need any help, i'm so desperate :(

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language

I hope it helps.

Comment: NSLocalizedString () is best way for it .... see above question link...

Answer (score 0):

*This question was asked many times.*

You can easily implement your own language system. The `NSLocalizedString` that Apple uses is a macro, which you could change or just make your own macro for localization. That way you can fully control what is being localized and what not and can change it at runtime. See those projects for example: [**TCLocalizer**](https://github.com/tcurdt/TCLocalizer) and [**DPLocalizationManager**](https://github.com/nullic/DPLocalizationManager).

**They both allow runtime localization of your view controllers.** And there are many more, such as:

- [Qlovr/QVLocalization](https://github.com/Qlovr/QVLocalization)
- [illoyd/CAFLocalizables](https://github.com/illoyd/CAFLocalizables)
- [mumensh/iOS-Localization](https://github.com/mumensh/iOS-Localization)

*All these links and libraries should help you figure out what exactly do you need and how to accomplish it.*

Comment: Thanks but i forget to add that. i do not want to create many xib files. Is there any solution for that. There will be one xib file. For example  "View.xib" and "View.strings" for every language

Comment: Of course there is. You can create outlets or labels and buttons in code and localise them manually.

Comment: i have lots of xib's and the strings are inside the xib files hardcoded.