# change langue on the fly IOS

Tags: ios, localization

I would like to make a button in the app , i want my app support Chinese and English. lot of the sample on the web require restart the app to take effect. is there any way to change the language in the App without restart the App ?

Comment: Check this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/20257557/844497

Answer (score 0):

Ive done something like this in my application.

saved my button or item text in different language other that english in [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

then in application load it check "Lang" keny value in NSUserDefaults.

if other than "eng" , it load that language.

if u put button or list with ability to select and change lang key in NSUserDefaults then the

only think u should do is to change all item text base on list or array u made in ur

application per language.