# In iOS Settings: set language specific default value for a MultiValue-Item

Tags: ios, localization, settings.bundle

in my iPhone-Project i have a Settings-Bundle with a MultiValue Item.
Now i would like to set the default value of the MultiValue Item language specific.

e.g:

```
User 1 with en: default value = 1
User 2 with de: default value = 2
User 3 with fr: default value = 3
```

of course 1,2 and 3 are possible values

Is this possible?

Thx!

Comment: I hope this [link][1] is helpful answer for you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language

Comment: that seems to work for apps. But I need it in the Settings-Bundle. Thanks anyway