# Change iOS app language without rebooting the device

Tags: ios, objective-c, localization

I did localisation for my iOS app.By the client order i need to make a modification i.e the app languages should change by button action. My previous localisation is works based on device language.Now i have to modify the application to change the language with out rebooting the device.

Comment: r u need tom change the language in button action

Comment: you can create a custom localisation procedure anytime which can be operated by a button inside the app. where were you stuck implementing such solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't change the language of the device in your application but you can change it just for your application by changing the `AppleLanguages` property in `NSUserDefaults`. Please note however I believe this still requires restarting the app itself but doesn't require a device restart.

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"nl", @"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
```

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language) another similar question that also maybe able to help you

Comment: the point is here not changing the language on the device programmatically, but changing the language inside the app by tapping a button. the _first_ is not possible via public API, the _second_ one is totally reasonable and can be done without any restriction.

Answer (score 5):

Create LocalizeHelper.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// some macros (optional, but makes life easy)

// Use "LocalizedString(key)" the same way you would use "NSLocalizedString(key,comment)"
#define LocalizedString(key) [[LocalizeHelper sharedLocalSystem] localizedStringForKey:(key)]

// "language" can be (for american english): "en", "en-US", "english". Analogous for other languages.
#define LocalizationSetLanguage(language) [[LocalizeHelper sharedLocalSystem] setLanguage:(language)]

@interface LocalizeHelper : NSObject

// a singleton:
+ (LocalizeHelper*) sharedLocalSystem;

// this gets the string localized:
- (NSString*) localizedStringForKey:(NSString*) key;

//set a new language:
- (void) setLanguage:(NSString*) lang;

@end
```

and in .m file

```
// LocalizeHelper.m
#import "LocalizeHelper.h"

// Singleton
static LocalizeHelper* SingleLocalSystem = nil;

// my Bundle (not the main bundle!)
static NSBundle* myBundle = nil;


@implementation LocalizeHelper


//-------------------------------------------------------------
// allways return the same singleton
//-------------------------------------------------------------
+ (LocalizeHelper*) sharedLocalSystem {
    // lazy instantiation
    if (SingleLocalSystem == nil) {
        SingleLocalSystem = [[LocalizeHelper alloc] init];
    }
    return SingleLocalSystem;
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------
// initiating
//-------------------------------------------------------------
- (id) init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        // use systems main bundle as default bundle
        myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    }
    return self;
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------
// translate a string
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// you can use this macro:
// LocalizedString(@"Text");
- (NSString*) localizedStringForKey:(NSString*) key {
    // this is almost exactly what is done when calling the macro NSLocalizedString(@"Text",@"comment")
    // the difference is: here we do not use the systems main bundle, but a bundle
    // we selected manually before (see "setLanguage")
    return [myBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"" table:nil];
}


//-------------------------------------------------------------
// set a new language
//-------------------------------------------------------------
// you can use this macro:
// LocalizationSetLanguage(@"German") or LocalizationSetLanguage(@"de");
- (void) setLanguage:(NSString*) lang {

    // path to this languages bundle
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lang ofType:@"lproj" ];
    if (path == nil) {
        // there is no bundle for that language
        // use main bundle instead
        myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    } else {

        // use this bundle as my bundle from now on:
        myBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];

        // to be absolutely shure (this is probably unnecessary):
        if (myBundle == nil) {
            myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
        }
    }
}


@end
```

For Setting language use

```
 LocalizationSetLanguage(@"ar");
```

For Getting Values use

self.Mylabel.text = LocalizedString(@"rent");

For each language you want to support you need a file named Localizable.strings. This works exactly as described in Apples documentation for localization.

```
// TABS

"buy" = "شراء";
"rent" = "إيجار";
"addListing" = "إضافة إعلان" ;
"calculator" = "دلالي" ;
"news" = "أخبار" ;
```

Comment: Thank you its working fine.But I am facing an issue if I kill the app again open means need a changed language..How can I save/get a current chosen language.