# Does setting default language by using below code is allowed by apple?

Tags: ios, iphone, localization, localizable.strings

In one of my application, I need to set the default language as French, if the language selected (device language) is non French.
I am using below code snippet, but I am afraid if this is allowed by apple or not.
Would this cause in rejection of the app over the app store. Please suggest.
Here is the code:-

```
NSArray *langOrder = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"fr", nil];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:langOrder forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];​
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a completely accepted way of doing it, however there are a few others as well. Look here for more potential solutions: [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1669645/1091402).