# How can I force StoryBoard localization with auto layout

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, autolayout, localizable.strings

I'm using localization for storyboard by auto layout for UI and localized strings for strings (I have one storyboard and add localization for strings only)

I have one project with two targets.

One of them should run only in English and the second should always run in Hebrew.

I tried to add a hack to force the application to be in Hebrew by adding this line to the main file:

```
NSUserDefaults * defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"he"] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

But, this solution works only after I run the application twice.

I found another solution,

> [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language/20257557#20257557)

but it's not working at all.

Can you help me?

Thanks...

Comment: Why use localization at all if you have separate targets for each language? Can you just add a different storyboard to each target?

Comment: Because all code is shared, The differences between targets is localization and some small isuues

Comment: You can still share your code with multiple targets, and get the localized string programmatically - see https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Harpy/blob/master/Harpy/Harpy.m for an example of forced localization.

Comment: I know, I'm using targets, but the localization definition is only in the project settings.

Comment: The problem is localization of UI not strings. In Auto layout there is concept for localized RTL to LTR by constraints. and this is my problem