# Force localize string on watch kit

Tags: ios, localization, watchkit

On iphone, we can do "force localisation" like this.

```
+ (void)setLanguage:(NSString*)language
{

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^
                  {
                      object_setClass([NSBundle mainBundle],[BundleEx class]);
                  });
    objc_setAssociatedObject([NSBundle mainBundle], &_bundle, language ? [NSBundle bundleWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:language ofType:@"lproj"]] : nil, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);
```

}

[How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

May I know how to do on watch kit (apple watch)? Is it same?