# iOS localization is broken with the upgrade iOs 9 + Xcode 7

Tags: ios, localization, ios9, xcode7

I localized my app in Italian and English, using the `Localizable.strings` file and the `NSLocalizedString macro`. I also enabled `base localization`. Everything works fine in the simulator and on devices with iOS 8, but on iOS 9 the app is always in english, even on devices with the italian language selected as default in the iPhone settings.
Does iOS 9 changes something with localization?

Here's a screenshot of the Xcode localization settings
[image: http://i.imgur.com/xc20yjj.png][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRcb5.png)

And of the device used for testing
[image: http://i.imgur.com/QCjn52u.png]

Thanks in advance

Comment: What language is your scheme running in? Select your app title in the breadcrumb in Xcode (next to the simulator selector) -> Edit Scheme... -> Run -> Options -> Application Language?

Comment: The Application Language is settled to the System Language.
Everything seems ok in fact I don't know where to look at

Comment: Looks like English has 4 files localised, but Italian only has 2–could that be the reason? Which files are localised in your project?

Comment: I removed the english localization because it was a copy of the base but the app is still in english.
I will investigate this strange problem in the next days.
It seems that it ignores the default language in the settings and load the base strings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Solved, the "problem" was the key "Localization native development region" in the info.plist file. It was setted to Italy, so when the app was running in a device with the Italian language as default it was showing the Base localization version of the strings (the English version).
Changing the value to United States solved the issue.

Comment: I met the same problem. But I change the value to 'Unite States' did not help. My 2nd language is Chinese Traditional.

Comment: However, if I change the 'Region' setting of the iOS device to 'Unite States', I can see Chinese on my app then. Why does the 'Region' setting matter?

Comment: Your base strings file is in english or in chinese?

Comment: My base string file is in english

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't help, this is a very strange behavior

Comment: I checked the return value of [NSLocale preferredLanguages], it shows 3 objects.. 'zh-TW', 'en-TW', 'zh-Hans-TW'. The first one supposed to be 'zh-Hant-TW'. It will return 'zh-Hant' in iOS 8.x. My device language is Traditional Chinese', and my region is 'Taiwan'

Answer (score 2):

I have another solution, just remove the key 'Localizations' in info.plist.
It works for my case.

Comment: This worked for me. Project-Info-Localization and info.plist-Localization was different in my case.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround.
The root cause of this problem is Apple changed the "Language Identifiers" in iOS 9, please refer [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2418/_index.html).

Since `NSLocalizedString()` (and variants thereof) access the `"AppleLanguages"` key in `NSUserDefaults` to determine what the user's settings for preferred languages are. I forced `NSLocalizedString` to use a specific language with is noted as their old Language Identifiers in older iOS versions once I found their Language ID is in new format. In another word, I made a mapping of `"AppleLanguages"` key value.

To do this, please refer to: [How to force NSLocalizedString to use a specific language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language)

I think Apple did a very bad job in compatibility!!

Comment: Note that I cannot find a way to add a localized resource with code "zh-TW", I can only add "zh", "zh-Hant" or "zh-Hant-TW" only. Not sure if it is a bug of apple.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out you have add the languages you want the app to support.  You have to manually select it to localization.