# Why the localization is not working in Xcode7 & iOS 9?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization

I am developing in iOS 9 with Xcode 7.

Before developing in iOS 9 , the localization is work fine. But at the iOS 9 with Xcode 7 , the localization is not working.

For example:

I set the `backbarButton` and the title is `Back`.

```
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Back", nil) style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];
```

And I also set the `Localizable.strings`.

Set `"Back" = "返回";` At the **(Chinese (Simplified))**.And  set the `"Back" = "Back";` in **`Base`**.

[image]

But it always show **English** when it run on my iPhone 5C(iOS version is 9).

Why the localization is not working in Xcode 7 & iOS 9 ?

Did I missing something ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32733000/988169

Comment: @pkc456 I have set the "Localization native development region" to United States , but it still not working.

Comment: are you change the language in phone settings? Or change the setting in your app?

Comment: @HariKrishnan.P Yes , I have change the language in my phone.

Comment: chines language only not working or other language also cannot work?

Comment: I know it's an old post, but do you found any solution ? I've the same problem...