# Different base (development) language and fallback language

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, internationalization, xcode7

There are many resources out there dealing with translation but I'm still confused.

My goal is to develop an app in German and translate the storyboard and strings used in the code. German must be the base for translations into additional languages.

The app will be translated into English at least. If the device preferred language is not German, the fallback language must be English. For example, on an "Spanish" device the English strings are displayed.

But if I change CFBundleDevelopmentRegion to German, the fallback language will be German (according to this [Technical Note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1828/_index.html)).

How can I have different development and fallback languages?

Thanks a lot for the clarifications.

Comment: Usually it is not recommended to force the language of the app, it should be done according to the user's preferred languages. However, you can check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language where you can find some solutions to it.

Comment: Thanks,  Dániel. But I don't want to force any language. I just want to make sure that English is displayed if no translation for the preferred language is provided. This should be achieved even if the Development Region is German.