# Disable localization in UILocalNotification alertBody

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nslocalizedstring

I'm using local notifications in my chat app (using Long polling). The problem is when the user receives a new chat while the app is in the background, the message affected to `UILocalNotification alertBody` is replaced with the localized string of that message. 
How do I tell the UILocalNotification to use the actual message and not its localized value?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33120935/uilocalnotification-nslocalizedstring-uses-language-of-device) might be answer for you..