# Reading Localized String

Tags: ios, swift, localized

I have an app that I'd like to be able to get the localized string for a certain key, regardless of what my current localization on the iPhone is.

I have the following in an en.lproj localized strings file

"Black" = "Black";

In the es.lproj localized strings file I have

"Black" = "Negro";

So what I would like to do is get the Spanish string when my phone is in the US and set up accordingly

I'm using the following code:

```
let bpath:String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("es", ofType: "lproj")! as String
let bundle = NSBundle(path: bpath as String)
let thisWord="Black"
let ourWord=NSLocalizedString(thisWord, bundle: bundle!, comment: "")
```

I'm expecting to get "Negro" in the value for ourWord, but I always get "Black"

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I think you are trying to forge a language no? Check if this helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1669645/how-to-force-nslocalizedstring-to-use-a-specific-language.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually my code works fine. I had made the stupid mistake of not setting the "Localizable.strings" file as localized.

Feeling pretty dumb right now

Answer (score 1):

Localization settings apply based on the settings you set in your phone not the location. If your phone is setup to display an Application Language of Spanish then you will see the appropriate string. To configure Application Language settings so you can test this you need to edit your Scheme.

In Xcode 7.1+ Goto Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme

Then change the Application Language and/or Region to simulate what a user would see who has an iPhone configured for a region or language other than English in the US.

*(Switch it to Spanish and then debug the app on the device again to see the updated localized strings)*.

[image: 1]

Comment: Sorry, but that's not what I'm asking.  I can get that to work, but I want the string for a language that is not set in the settings options.